# How to get rid of default white launch Powered by react-native screen in ios?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

How to get rid of this default white launch screen in ios? I have deployed my app in App store , this screen is still showing in live version . I want to start my app with my custom splash screen. 
How to solve this? anybody can help please.
Thank you in advance.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 2):

In iOS content displayed on Splash screen is loaded from `LaunchScreen.xib` file.
To view this file:

1. Open your project in xcode.
2. On the left menu, expand your project node and then expand your project framework node.
3. There you will find LaunchScreen.xib file, open that.
4. Once you open it, you will find configuration settings on right bar where you set the attributes of the content to be displayed, but before that make sure that you have placed your necessary image files on image assets, in order to be accessible from the configurations settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) in order to hide the default splash screen configured in ios/*YourAppName*/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib.

This default splash screen will still be seen very briefly so you can get rid of the text in it and change the colour if needed (in your favorite IDE) to have a nice transition to the next screen (your custom react-native splash screen).